# chai js expect property value empty array

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a unit test using chai js assertion, and was wondering how to expect arrays with zero length as values.

My Test function expect statement:

```
return expect(functionRetuningPromise()).to eventually.have.property("key1", []);
```

Console Output on running mocha:

```
AssertionError: expected { otherkey: otherVal, key1: [] } to have a property 'key1' of [], but got []
```

I have tried `deep.property`, `key1:"[]"` with no success

Comment: There is always the "empty" assertion http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#empty

Comment: @JasonSperske: But will it work if I have to check the value of a property? And not just a simple variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ignored there's a section of change in assertion for properties. So, what made it work for me was :

```
return expect(functionRetuningPromise()).to.eventually.have.property("key1").that.eql([]);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's working? [] == [] is false (reference equality)!

Comment: yes, this works, because of the use of eql instead of equal. Eql makes use of the deep-eql-project (https://medium.com/building-ibotta/testing-arrays-and-objects-with-chai-js-4b372310fe6d)

Answer (score 16):

I think this is a little plainer

```
expect( value ).to.be.an( "array" ).that.is.empty
```

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
return 

expect(functionRetuningPromise()).to.eventually.have.property("key1").that.satisfy(function (value) {
  expect(value).to.be.instanceof(Array);
  expect(value).to.have.length.above(0);
  return true;
})
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```js
expect(value).to.deep.equal([]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Be careful, this solution is not correct. This will pass even when your array has elements

Answer (score 1):

In chaiJs, I do the following. Check if it is an array and has a length of 0.

```
expect(array).to.be.instanceOf(Array).and.lengthOf(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with **chai.js** and **should**:

```
const should = chai.should();

res.should.have.lengthOf(0)
```

Link for more information https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should.