# I expect there is an easier way top check for an object to have an empty array

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm using chai and sinon to write some tests.

I have this object:

```
{
    payload: {
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: []
    },
    type: 'FOO:BAR'
}
```

And I want to write an expectation that the object contains a property called bar that is an empty object.

I have this for `foo`:

```
expect(myObject).to.have.property('foo', 'bar')
```

Which is nice and succinct. Compare it to this rather long expectation:

```
expect(myObject).to.have.property('bar').that.is.an('array').with.property('length', 0)
```

I write it like this both because property does a compare by reference if I use `property('bar', [])`, and based off of the example in this [cheatcheet](https://gist.github.com/yoavniran/1e3b0162e1545055429e#sinon-chai) (see the property section).

Is there a less verbose way to write this expectation?

Comment: `that.is.an('array').that.is.empty`

Comment: Does [`.that.eql([])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35997618/4642212) work?

Comment: @AmitJoki I have an aversion to abusing property getters, but that might work

Comment: @Xufox I will try `.that.deep.equals([])`

Comment: I don't think .that.eql([]) will work as you have 2 different references to two different arrays. [] == [] returns false in JS

Comment: @RaduDiță Have you read the linked answer and its comments? _“Are you sure that's working? `[] == []` is `false` (reference equality)!”_ — _“Yes. `.eql` does a deep match. https://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql”_.

Comment: @Xufox `.that.deep.equals([])` works, do you want to post the answer or shall I?

Comment: Ah, just finished my answer and read through the comments here.  @Xufox if you want to post a `eql` answer I'll delete mine since it looks like you were actually the first to suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `sinon` you can use [`sinon.assert.match`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.0/assertions/#sinonassertmatchactual-expectation) to test that:

> the value...be not `null` or `undefined` and have at least the same properties as `expectation`

This checks that `obj` contains *at least* `payload` with a `foo` and `bar` of the expected values:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

const obj = {
  payload: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: []
  },
  type: 'FOO:BAR'
};

it('should match', () => {
  sinon.assert.match(obj, {
    payload: {
      foo: 'bar',
      bar: []
    }
  });  // Success!
});
```

---

Another option (looks like it was suggested first by @Xufox in the comments) is [`.eql`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) from `chai` which:

> Asserts that the target is deeply equal to the given `obj`

This checks that `obj.payload` is deeply equal to `{ foo: 'bar', bar: [] }`:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const obj = {
  payload: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: []
  },
  type: 'FOO:BAR'
};

it('should match', () => {
  expect(obj.payload).to.eql({
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: []
  });  // Success!
});
```